# reading data from sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

I have stored my images in sqlite database.. i am reading the datas from db using the following query...but the "select"query not working ...if anyone knows,pls help me to resolve..

```
const char *phssqlStatement="select fld_image ,fld_path from tbl_image where fld_path like ?";
        sqlite3_stmt *phscompiledStatement;

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, phssqlStatement, -1, &phscompiledStatement, NULL);
        printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        //sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,1,[str_imgname1_site UTF8String],250, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        //sqlite3_bind_text(phscompiledStatement,1,[zoomedImageURL UTF8String],350,SQLITE_STATIC);
         sqlite3_bind_text(phscompiledStatement, 1, [zoomedImageURL UTF8String],350, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQLite query should be more like:

```
const char *phssqlStatement="select fld_image ,fld_path from tbl_image where fld_path like '%?%'";
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to number your input var like this:

```
const char *phssqlStatement="select fld_image ,fld_path from tbl_image where fld_path like ?1";
```

Comment: Try like this: const char *phssqlStatement="select fld_image ,fld_path from tbl_image where fld_path like '?1'";